# How to delete duplicate lines in a file...AWK, SED, UNIQ not working on my file

Tags: sed, awk, duplicates, lines, uniq

I find many ways to do this, `AWK`, `SED`, `UNIQ`, but none of them are working on my file.

I want to delete duplicate lines.  Here is an example of part of my file:

```
KTBX
KFSO
KCLK
KTBX
KFSO
KCLK
PAJZ
PAJZ
```

NOTE: I had to manually add line feeds when I cut and pasted from the file...for some reason it was putting all the variables on one line.  Makes me think that my 44,000 line text file actually has only "1" line?  Is there a way to modify it so I can delete dups?

Comment: If your file does not have more than one line, it's going to be tough for us to recommend a way to delete duplicate lines.

Comment: If I VI my file, it has 44,000 lines.

Comment: donnot know if you care about the order, if not. simply 'sort your.file | uniq' should do it.

Comment: That worked...thanks!  Not sure why those others think there are no lines.

Comment: @Corepuncher did you try `awk '!a[$0]++' file` ?

Comment: @Kent yes, I tried that one.  I typed that, then > newfile , and the newfile was same as old with duplicate entries.

Comment: You don't need `sort file | uniq` when `sort -u file` works just as well but clearly you have some issues with your input file format so how can you KNOW that what you're getting spit out of your command is what you want? What does `wc -l file` tell you? How about `head -10 file | cat -v`?

Answer (score 4):

You can see all non-printed characters with this command:

```
od -c oldfile
```

If all your records are on one line, you can use [sed to replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1853040/2327328) a whitespace (space, tab, newline) with a linebreak:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' oldfile > oldfile.1
```

Once you have multiple lines, this awk one-liner:

```
awk '!x[$0]++' oldfile.1 > newfile
```

my outfile:

```
KTBX
KFSO
KCLK
PAJZ
```

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting. Interestingly, this didn't work for me on OSX when the source file contained windows line endings ( \r\n ). awk was unable to recognize the duplicates. Converting it via dos2unix made it work.

Answer (score 1):

**Perl One-Liner:**

perl -nle 'unless($hash{$_}++){print $_}' file

Comment: Nice. I saw a similar technique for eliminating duplicates in an array.