# How to convert space separated text to lines in Bash

Tags: linux, string, bash

I have a simple string:

```
 foo bar boo you too
```

I'm looking for an easy way in bash on the command line (not in a script) to take this string in via a pipe or input redirection and convert it to

```
 foo
 bar
 boo
 you
 too
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853009/replace-all-whitespace-with-a-line-break-paragraph-mark-to-make-a-word-list). i.e. `tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$string"` (or use one of the better multi-space solutions from the post)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use 'tr' to translate the space to a new line:

```
~$ echo 'foo bar boo you too' | tr ' ' '\n'
foo
bar
boo
you
too
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "one two three" | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

A working solution using `grep` and regular expressions:

```
echo "foo bar boo you too" | grep -oE "[a-z]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

[in Bash] lit.

```
$ echo "foo bar boo you too" | ( read -a A; printf '%s\n' "${A[@]}"; )
foo
bar
boo *
you
too
```